# How to make XSL not convert my xsl:element and xsl:attribute names to lowercase?

Tags: xml, xslt

Hello StackOverFlow community,

I have created a simple XSL to convert a XML file into another.

The output XML file needs to follow a schema that I received from a vendor which describes its elements following camelCase standard.

for instance, I need to create the element:

```
<bfr5:remision>
  <brf5:infoBasica folio="19190" refID="19190" rfcReceptor="TTTTT" rfcEmisor="SSSSS5">
    <infoEspecial valor="19190"></infoEspecial>
  </brf5:infoBasica>
</bfr5:remision>
```

However, when I run my XSL, it changes the element and attribute names all to lowercase.

```
<bfr5:remision>
  <brf5:infobasica folio="19190" refid="19190" rfcreceptor="TTTTT" rfcemisor="SSSSS5">
    <infoespecial valor="19190"></infoespecial>
  </brf5:infobasica>
</bfr5:remision>
```

This is the entire XSL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"                              xmlns:bfr5="http://www.buzonfiscal.com/ns/xsd/bf/remision/52">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

  <xsl:element name="bfr5:Remision">

  <xsl:attribute name="version">5.2</xsl:attribute>

  <!-- Required for InfoBasica -->
  <xsl:variable name="custRegNo"    select="/Document/Letter/Customer/custRegNo"/>
  <xsl:variable name="invoiceNo"    select="/Document/Letter/InvoiceDetails/InvoiceHeader/invoiceNo"/>
  <xsl:variable name="folioNo"      select="/Document/Letter/InvoiceDetails/InvoiceHeader/folioAssign"/>
  <xsl:variable name="asignaFolio">false</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="lessorTaxId"  select="/Document/Letter/LetterDetails/Lessor/lessorTaxId"/>

  <!-- Required for InfoAdicional -->
  <xsl:variable name="paymentType"        select="/Document/Letter/InvoiceDetails/InvoiceHeader/paymentType"/>
  <xsl:variable name="subTotal"           select="/Document/Letter/InvoiceDetails/InvoiceHeader/totalDueWithLateCharge"/>
  <xsl:variable name="total"              select="/Document/Letter/InvoiceDetails/InvoiceHeader/totalDueWithLateCharge"/>
  <xsl:variable name="paymentMethod"       select="/Document/Letter/InvoiceDetails/InvoiceHeader/paymentMethod"/>
  <xsl:variable name="invoiceType"  select="/Document/Letter/InvoiceDetails/InvoiceHeader/invoiceType"/>
  <xsl:variable name="expeditionPlace"    select="/Document/Letter/InvoiceDetails/InvoiceHeader/expeditionPlace"/>

  <!-- Required for Emisor -->
  <xsl:variable name="regimen"  select="'Régimen General De Ley Personas Morales'"/>

  <!-- Required for DomicilioFiscal -->
  <xsl:variable name="addressStreet"    select="/Document/Letter/LetterDetails/Lessor/LessorAddress/addressStreetNameAndNumber"/>
  <xsl:variable name="addressCity"      select="/Document/Letter/LetterDetails/Lessor/LessorAddress/addressCity"/>
  <xsl:variable name="addressState"     select="/Document/Letter/LetterDetails/Lessor/LessorAddress/addressState"/>
  <xsl:variable name="addressCountry"   select="/Document/Letter/LetterDetails/Lessor/LessorAddress/addressCountry"/>
  <xsl:variable name="addressZip"       select="/Document/Letter/LetterDetails/Lessor/LessorAddress/addressPostalCode"/>

  <xsl:element name="bfr5:InfoBasica">

    <xsl:attribute name="rfcEmisor"><xsl:value-of select="$lessorTaxId"/></xsl:attribute>        
    <xsl:attribute name="rfcReceptor"><xsl:value-of select="$custRegNo"/></xsl:attribute>        
    <xsl:attribute name="refID"><xsl:value-of select="$invoiceNo"/></xsl:attribute>        
    <xsl:attribute name="folio"><xsl:value-of select="$folioNo"/></xsl:attribute>        
    <xsl:attribute name="asignaFolio"><xsl:value-of select="$asignaFolio"/></xsl:attribute>

    <xsl:element name="InfoEspecial">
      <xsl:attribute name="atributo">Invoice Number</xsl:attribute>          
      <xsl:attribute name="valor"><xsl:value-of select="$invoiceNo"/></xsl:attribute>        
    </xsl:element>      
  </xsl:element>

  <xsl:element name ="bfr5:InfoAdicional">

    <xsl:attribute name="formaDePago"><xsl:value-of select="$paymentType"/></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="subTotal"><xsl:value-of select="$subTotal"/></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="total"><xsl:value-of select="$total"/></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="metodoDePago"><xsl:value-of select="$paymentMethod"/></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="tipoDeComprobante"><xsl:value-of select="$invoiceType"/></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="lugarExpedicion"><xsl:value-of select="$expeditionPlace"/></xsl:attribute>

  </xsl:element>

  <xsl:element name ="bfr5:Emisor">        
    <xsl:element name="bfr5:RegimenFiscal">          
      <xsl:attribute name="Regimen"><xsl:value-of select="$regimen"/></xsl:attribute>              
    </xsl:element>      
  </xsl:element>

  <xsl:element name ="bfr5:DomicilioFiscal">

    <xsl:attribute name="calle"><xsl:value-of select="$addressStreet"/></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="municipio"><xsl:value-of select="$addressCity"/></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="estado"><xsl:value-of select="$addressState"/></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="pais"><xsl:value-of select="$addressCountry"/></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="codigoPostal"><xsl:value-of select="$addressZip"/></xsl:attribute>


  </xsl:element>

</xsl:element>
```

I'm using Internet Explorer 10 to process. Later, I will port this code into Linux and run it using $xsltproc.

```
<bfr5:remision xmlns:bfr5="http://www.buzonfiscal.com/ns/xsd/bf/remision/52" version="5.2">
  <bfr5:infobasica folio="19190" refid="19190" rfcreceptor="XAXX010101000" rfcemisor="DLM131002M75" asignafolio="false">
    <infoespecial valor="19190" atributo="Invoice Number"></infoespecial>
    <bfr5:infoadicional lugarexpedicion="Mexico DF" tipodecomprobante="ingreso" metododepago="Transferencia electrónica de fondos" total="2.00" subtotal="2.00" formadepago="Pago en una sola Exhibición">
      <bfr5:emisor>
        <bfr5:regimenfiscal regimen="SCRAMBLE l De Ley Personas Morales"></bfr5:regimenfiscal>
        <bfr5:domiciliofiscal codigopostal="111950" pais="MEXICO" estado="D.F" municipio="SCRAMBLED CITY" calle="SCRAMBLE ADDRESS"></bfr5:domiciliofiscal>
      </bfr5:emisor>
    </bfr5:infoadicional>
 </bfr5:infobasica>
</bfr5:remision>
```

Comment: Which processor does that?

Comment: Can we see your xslt being it is very crucial to your post? I am very interested to see how letter cases change after being declared in `<xsl:element>` and `<xsl:attribute>` tags because I can't reproduce.

Comment: Hi Michael.hor257k and Parfait - I have added the XSLT. As I mentioned now, I'm just processing via I.E10 - But later I will port this over into Linux and run via xsltproc.

Cheers.

Comment: Can you show us how you use XSLT with IE 10? IE does not even have an XSLT processor of its own but simply uses MSXML 3 or MSXML 6, which are part of the OS. And I have never heard that MSXML does anything like changing the case of letters in result element or attribute nodes.

Comment: Hi Martin, I set this line right after the <xml> tag in my XML file that I want to transform. <?xml-stylesheet href="transform_xml.xsl" type="text/xsl"?> . Then I just drag it over the IE browser.

Answer (score 1):

Ok - It seems this is happening because of Internet Explorer.

I have ported the XSL and XML into Linux and run via xsltproc. It no longer turns the element and attribute names into lowercase. It keeps my camelCase now.

Regards,
Davi